# Unable to hide a column from the "Quick Edit" grid using JSLink

Tags: list, development, powershell, jslink, quick-edit

I have a custom site column named "Item Number". now i want to force this column to be un-editable inside the Quick Edit grid. now when i try to edit the site column (Site Setting>> Site Column >>click on the column), the url will be as follow:-

```
http://..../_layouts/15/fldedit.aspx?field=ID1&Source=%2F%5Flayouts%2F15%2Fmngfield%2Easpx%3FFilter%3DAll%2520Groups
```

which mean the field ID = ID1. so to be able to hide the column from all the Quick edit grid , i wrote the following JSLINK script (HideColumnsINGrid.js):-

```
(function () {
    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = overrideContext.Templates || {};
    overrideContext.Templates.OnPreRender = function(ctx) {
        var statusField = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function(f) {
            return f.ID === 'ID1';
        });
        if (statusField) {
            statusField[0].AllowGridEditing = false;
        }
    }
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();
```

then i wrote the following powershell script to apply the above JSlink to the field as follow:-

```
 $web = Get-SPWeb http://vstg01
    $field = $web.Fields["Item Number"]
    $field.JSLink = "Style%20Library/JS/HideColumnsINGrid.js"
    $field.Update($true

)
```

now the power shell script did not raise any error , but the Item number can still be edited from the Qucik Edit ?so can anyone adivce on this please ?

Thanks

Comment: If your js file is being loaded in New/Edit form?

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela now i added "alert(12345);" inside the script but it did not get fire,, also the page source does not have any referecne to the script... but if i am not wrong the script is not supposed to load inside the new/edit forms it should fire if i am inside the quick edit grid ,, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer

```
(function () {

var fieldContext = {
    Templates: {
        Fields: {
            ID1: {
                View: function (ctx, b) {
                    b.AllowGridEditing = false;
                    return ctx.CurrentItem.ID1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(fieldContext);
   })();
```

You need to apply that JSLink to view not in field.

Comment: so you mean i need to add this to the all the list's views, and also to any additional views  ? this will not be a good approach as i have many views and i do not want to be editing them separately ,, i want to define this based on the item not based on the view,,and have the effect automatically inside all the views... what do u think ?

Comment: can you adivce on my comment please?